# Delete custom EAV attributes from the database

Tags: attributes, database, custom-options, eav

I want to remove unused EAV attributes directly from the database before I move my store live. Attributes can be found in `eav_attribute` table, can I delete attributes from this table? Is it safe? Or do I also need to edit other EAV tables?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

See [`Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup::removeAttribute()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php#L986). It takes two arguments - the first is the entity code, and the second is the attribute code.

***Edit -** to run from a non-installation scope:*

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_product','attr_code');
```

Comment: Thnk you. I understand how to use it in a setup script of a module:

`$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_product', 'my_attribute1');` or `$installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'my_attribute2');`

But is there a way to use this code in a separate file? I'd like to place the file in the root folder (where Magento's `index.php`), so that it would be possible to call the script in web browser: `example.com/delete_attributes.php/`. Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Updated my response.

Comment: What code changes i need to do, to delete a custom customer attribute?

Comment: @shasikanth - it's really a separate question, but swap `catalog/setup` with `customer/setup`, `catalog_setup` with `customer_setup`, and `catalog_product` with `customer`.

Answer (score 12):

The first rule of Magento is: Never edit the database directly.
I admit that I broke this rule on numerous occasions, so...
you can delete the attributes from `eav_attribute`, the constraints with `ON DELETE CASCADE` should cleanup the rest of the tables.
But I still think you should take the clean way:

```
$attributeId = 55;
Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId)->delete();
```

It shouldn't take long and you will feel at peace with yourself because you didn't break the rules.
It's not important what method you choose, but backing up your DB is, in both cases.

Comment: I always try to avoid editing database, but it is much faster to do it this way :) and this time it is only for testing (not for production site). So is this query enough to get rid of the attribute, or do I need to do something more:
`DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code = "my_attribute";`

Comment: This should be eoungh. Just make sure there aren't 2 attributes with the same code, for different entities.

Answer (score 5):

`DELETE FROM eav_attribute WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code = "some_attr_code";`

is a **working** solution, I used it many times.

Especially if you remove extension and Magento still want to call unexisting attribute model