# Cannot access Manage Categories in admin. Source model not found for attribute error

Tags: category, attributes, magento-1.9.3.2

We had an issue with an old instance and basically, our SSH root was corrupt and we couldn't upgrade any longer. So, I took a database backup and installed it on a fresh installation. I then added our new theme, and everything seemingly works fine but when I try to access the Manage Categories area in admin.  I get the error pasted at the end of this post.

It looks like it is basically looking for something from our old theme, which in retrospect, perhaps I should've reverted to the default Magento theme before doing the DB backup I used to restore on this fresh instance, but live and learn.

To remedy the issue I did the following:

1. Deleted the record looking for the attribute **ico_page_heading_textalign** in the database. That did nothing.
2. Deleted all records referring to Atelier, our old theme. That took the whole darn thing down :)
3. Restored the whole site to before I started this exercise.
4. Uploaded all the files/folder (named Icotheme) from my old theme into the app>code>local folder, including the file from the error.

Here is the error:

```
a:5:{i:0;s:126:"Source model "icotheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_textalign" not found for attribute "ico_page_heading_textalign"";i:1;s:4538:"#0 /var/www/html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Abstract.php(390): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "i...')
```

I still can't access the Manage Categories so I am hoping someone here can help!

Please see the entire error report below.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This error is related that for category dropdown custom attribute, there is one source model define that is not exist in your magento installation. You can try to delete the category attribute from database, It will delete all the reference of attribute:

```
<?php
include 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app();
$setup = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/setup','catalog_setup');
$setup->removeAttribute('catalog_category','ico_page_heading_textalign');
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/5469/delete-custom-eav-attributes-from-the-database)

Comment: Thx Pankaj. Are you saying to simply delete the db record or run this php file to do it?

Comment: Run this php file to do this

Comment: Last question, sorry. I'm just going to make this into a php file, drop it into my root, go to it to run it and delete it. Sounds right?

Comment: Yes perfect ...

Comment: Still broke but the error changed so I am going to "rinse and repeat" your method until done. The new error was "Source model "icotheme/system_config_source_category_attribute_pageheading" not found for attribute "ico_page_heading_style"  so I'll sub the ico_page_heading_textalign with ico_page_heading_style and so on until it works. I'll be back to update. Thx again!

Comment: Thanks again Rankaj! I had to run through about 15-20 attributes but it is working now. Thumbs up!

Comment: Great, as it worked for you. select this as answer so that other can get benefit

Comment: I did but I still have a rep<15, so it is recorded but doesn't show apparently. Thx 1000 times again though!